# Can I RSVP a User to an Event they weren't invited to?

Tags: facebook, events

While Facebook Events typically work by the creator inviting Friends to the Event and then Friend's replying to the Invite (or RSVP if you like), I'm wondering if it's possible to  RSVP to a public event from the API for a Facebook user who **hasn't** been invited?

The use case is a website that displays the client's Events and has an "I'm attending" feature. Users could then authenticate with Facebook Connect and RSVP to events which will set them as an attendee on the Facebook Event.

The real issue is that users of the App won't be explicitly invited to each event, but as they are public events, I'm wondering if the invite is even required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `rsvp_event` permission for the user you can RSVP them to any event they have permission to join (i.e public events) 
See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#attending

Comment: I've created some test users for my Application and created a fake (public) event and can confirm it is possible to RSVP to public events regardless of if they have received an invite or not. Thanks!